# string.include? doesn't work as expected

Tags: ruby, parsing

I am trying to scrape URLs and Javascript code from given pages. So first I wrote this to find out whether it is working or not:

```
file.each_line do |line|
    if line.include? ".com" || ".net" || ".org" || "edu" || "()" || "var" || "javascript" || "html" || "http" || "www"
        puts "String includes above"
        puts line
        puts "\n"
    else 
        puts "String doesn't include above"
        puts line
        puts "\n"
    end
end
```

And in the given output I get this:

```
String doesn't include above
(function() {

String doesn't include above
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_us/all.js#xfbml=1";
```

I was not expecting to see this output as I thought these would be in the first condition. Why does 'include' behave like that? How can I fix it?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @sawa Sorry I had an internet connection issue, question part wasn't drafted.

Comment: Okay, not we got the question. But, in order to fix it, you need to tell what is wrong with your code. How is it not behaving like you wanted?

Comment: @sawa I added the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not how Ruby works (or any language that I know of). You would have to use `include?` multiple times:

```
if line.include?('.com') || line.include?('.net') ...
```

It would be better to use Regex with `String#=~`:

```
if line =~ /(\.com|\.net|\.org|\.edu)/i
```

Comment: I changed thie first line as `if line =~ /(\.com|\.net|\.org|\.edu|\()|\var|\javascript|\html|\http|\www|\text-align|\function()/i`
And getting output for `var site="s18101dentist"` for the else part. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: The backslash is the escape character in Regex, you don't need it for everything. You need to escape the periods which is why I used it. You should learn the basics of Regex, it is very useful. If you don't know Regex, maybe use a simpler method (like making a custom method that loops over an array and checks `include?` on each element)